# Print HEX value of packet content

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, libpcap

I am using libpcap for packet sniffing. I want to print out the packet contents in HEX like we do in Wireshark. How do I do that? Let us say I want to print the HEX value of the 21st byte of the TCP segment(The 1st byte of the options, which is generally 0x02 for MSS), how do I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with: char c = tcp_packet[21]; printf ("Hex = 0x%02x\n", c);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char data[]; // byte array with packet content;
int start; // starting offset 
int end; // ending offset

int i;

for (i = start & ~15; i < end; i++)
{
    if  ((i & 15) == 0) 
       printf("%04x ",i);
    printf((i<start)?"   ":"%02x%c",(unsigned char)data[i],((i+1)&15)?' ':'\n');
}
if ((i & 15) != 0)
    printf("\n");
```

It will printout the portion of the provided `data` buffer starting from `start` offset and up to the `end` offset;

Comment: Why are you masking what you print with 0xF? And why are you masking start with 0xFFFFFFF0? In this snippet start and end are not initialized. Was that intentional?

Comment: @grieve It is not my task to initialize the  `start` and `end`. As you may see the data[] array also has no specific dimension. these three are the inputs to the rest of the snippet that the OP should provide. I am not masking what i print with `0xF`. this is end of line detection.

Comment: what does line detection mean in binary data, and I still don't understand why you are masking start with 0xFFFFFFF0?

Comment: @grieve `end of line detection`; start & ~15 == start - start % 16.

Comment: Binary data does not have end of lines, and by doing `start = start % 16` you make it impossible to have a starting offset of 16 or higher.

Comment: Nevermind, now I see what you are doing. Kind of obfuscated though.

Comment: @grieve if you have these doubts then better compile it and see how it works. If you can't read it what I can do?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been i = start % 16, but I had misread your last comment. that would be i = start - (start % 16).